# Пригласить в круиз или на круиз?

Tags: предлоги

Подскажите, будьте добры: пригласить в (на) замечательный круиз?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заимствование из английского весьма недавнее, поэтому сложно судить об устоявшемся предлоге.

Если смотреть по частотности употребления, то в [НКРЯ](https://ruscorpora.ru/) 1 вхождение *на круиз* и 24 вхождения *в круиз*. Если обратиться к [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams), то там примерно такая же картина:

[image: частотность пар слов]

Интересно, что фраза *пригласить в круиз* имеет только 1 вхождение, а *отправиться в круиз* только 14 вхождений в НКРЯ.

Я полагаю, что *круиз*, будучи крайне новым словом, воспринимается как специфический синоним, возможно гипоним, словам *путешествие* или *странствие*, или как контекстный синоним слову *плавание*, поэтому и предлоги наследует от них: *пригласить в круиз/плавание/странствие/путешествие*.

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ, но предлагаю разобраться, как устроен [этот запрос](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=3&lex2=%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B8%D0%B7&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2) — такого рода запросами искать в НКРЯ проще и надёжнее.

Comment: Можно поставить расстояние 2 — результат будет тот же. Расстояние 1 нельзя, потому что между "пригласит" и "круиз" должен быть предлог. Но не суть, я просто предлагаю немного практиковаться нижним блоком настроек поиска, а не только верхним.